# sphinx search can not index again

Tags: sphinx, centos7

I'm running sphinx search and can index successfully the first time, but not for an entirely new index on the same machine.

When I try to delete the old index files and re-index new data, `indexer` crashes.

The reason I think it's something machine specific is that when i spin up a new VM I'm able to index the same files, so I don't think it's something to do with invalid documents - must be something to do with re-indexing on the same machine. I've even tried to re-install sphinx.

So is there some file or config which I am supposed to delete to be able to index again on the same machine with brand new files? I don't want to `--rotate` since i don't need the old index anymore (and don't have twice the disk space).

Comment: is searched running when do this? If searchd is actively serving the index, indexer can't rebuild it. That's the point of the --rotate switch.   -- but frankly it sounds like simply dont have enough disk space, indexer uses a bunch of temporally files. You would need at least x3 the size of the index. (original + temporally + new). If you dont have, that will have to delete the existing index before indexing.

Comment: @barryhunter thanks. I've stopped searchd, and deleted all my old index files before trying to run `indexer` again

Answer (score 0):

Try to run indexer with `sphinx` user access:

**Debian:**

```
sudo -u sphinxsearch --rotate --all
```

**CentOS:**

```
sudo -u sphinx --rotate --all
```